# Cannot Install ruby-audio on OSX-10.9.2 Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I recently update my OSX version to 10.9.2. The ruby-audio gem is failing with the following warnings and errors. What can I do so that libFLAC.8.dylib can be found?

```
gem install ruby-audio -v '1.6.1'

31 warnings generated.
compiling ra_soundinfo.c
compiling rubyaudio_ext.c
linking shared-object rubyaudio_ext.bundle
ld: file not found: /usr/local/lib/libFLAC.8.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [rubyaudio_ext.bundle] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that flac and libogg were previously installed by brew but the links were lost in usr/local/lib due to OS update so I had to reinstall it. I did the following and ruby-audio was installed successfully.

```
brew remove flac
brew install flac
brew remove libogg
brew install libogg
```